# How to load firebase realtime data into a recycler view in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

When I try to view the list of data coming from realtime firebase no information is displayed

My adapter:

```
class MarcacaoAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MarcacaViewHolder>() {

    private var items = listOf<Marcacao>()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MarcacaViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_lista, parent, false)

        return MarcacaViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MarcacaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}
```

My view holder:

```
class MarcacaViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private val textviewData = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDataM)
    private val textviewHora = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvHoraM)

    fun bind (item: Marcacao){
        textviewData.text = item.dia
        textviewHora.text = item.hora
    }
}
```

My activity list:

```
class ListaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val adapterMarcacao = MarcacaoAdapter()

    private var tvDataM: TextView? = null
    private var tvHoraM: TextView? = null

    private lateinit var mDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mRecycler : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mArrayList : ArrayList<Marcacao>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista)

        mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        mArrayList = arrayListOf<Marcacao>()
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data")
        }
}
```

I would like some help to identify why my recycler view is not loading information from firebase.

Comment: None of your code seems to load any data from Firebase yet, so I recommend starting with that.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code which is related to getting data from Firebase.